# AjaxFileUpload get file stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to get file `System.IO.Stream` with AjaxFileUpload like this. This is clasical FileUpload component.

```
System.IO.Stream theStream = fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;
```

Can somebody show me how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can temporarily save the file, and then read it to get your FileStream. It's maybe a bit dirty, but it worked for me.

VB.NET:

```
Dim tempPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()
yourAjaxFileUpload.SaveAs(tempPath)
Using fs As FileStream = File.OpenRead(tempPath)
    'Do stuff with fs here
End Using
File.Delete(tempPath)
```

C#:

```
string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
yourAjaxFileUpload.SaveAs(tempPath);
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(tempPath)) {
    //do stuff with fs here
}
File.Delete(tempPath);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are handling the `UploadComplete` event, then you can get the stream from the `GetStreamContents` (as a stream) and `GetContents` (as a byte array) methods of the `AjaxFileUploadEventArgs` event arguments

e.g.

```
protected void afu_OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs file) 
{ 
    using (var stream = file.GetStreamContents())
    {
        // Read the stream...
    }
}
```

You can see what's available in the source code for [`AjaxFileUploadEventArgs`](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Server/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUploadEventArgs.cs) - there's much more than in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to Conversion before you save image(Ex:Png to jpg).Below might help on **asyncfileuploader** in **ajaxcontroltoolkit**

```
   Protected Sub FileUploadComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Try
        Dim id As String = Session("MBRId")
        Dim contentType As String = AsyncFileUploadProfileImage.ContentType
        If (contentType = "image/jpeg" Or contentType = "image/png") Then
            Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUploadProfileImage.FileName)
            Dim TOjpegImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(AsyncFileUploadProfileImage.FileContent)
            TOjpegImage.Save(Server.MapPath("img_prof/" + id + ".jpg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            Dim Ext As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(AsyncFileUploadProfileImage.FileName)
            'Commented working save due to conversion of image above
            ' AsyncFileUploadProfileImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("img_prof/") + id + Ext)
            lblMesg.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully"


        Else
            lblMesg.Text = "We support only images of type jpg and png"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        iHelperClasses.ErrorLogger.ErrorWriter("Method:FileUploadComplete()Error:" + ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```